# Excel VBA: Error copying a range from external workbook

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

I'm trying to copy a range of cells from a closed Workbook to the current Workbook but I always get ERROR 1004. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Sub Sheet2()
Dim Filt As String
Dim FilterIndex As Integer
Dim Title As String
Dim Multi As Boolean
Dim DataFile
Dim WBdata As Workbook

'I prompt the user to select the file to import
Filt = "Excel Workbook 2010 (*.xlsx),*.xlsx," & "Excel Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & "All Files (*.*),*.*"
FilterIndex = 1
Title = "Select file to import"
Multi = False
DataFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=Filt, FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, Title:=Title, MultiSelect:=Multi)

If DataFile = False Then
    MsgBox "No file was selected"
End If

'Open the file selected by the user
Set WBdata = Workbooks.Open(DataFile)

'Get the data
WBdata.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Copy _ ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Close and Select Cell (1,1)
WBdata.Close
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manager").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manager").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The debugger stops in `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Copy _ ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)`.

I tried the same syntax in a Test file and it went smooth but I cannot make it happen on the actual file. This is the code in the Test file:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
```

I appreciate all your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. You might want to exit the sub after `MsgBox "No file was selected"` so that the code doesn't give an error in this line `Set WBdata = Workbooks.Open(DataFile)` if say the user cancelled the dialog box? Or Handle the code in the `Else` part of the `If` Statement as shown in the code below
2. You are getting that error because you have not fully qualified the cells for example see the `.(DOT)` in `Cells(1, 1)` in the code below

Your code can be re-written as (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sheet2()
    Dim Filt As String, Title As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Multi As Boolean
    Dim DataFile
    Dim WBdata As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Filt = "Excel Workbook 2010 (*.xlsx),*.xlsx," & _
           "Excel Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
           "All Files (*.*),*.*"
    FilterIndex = 1
    Title = "Select file to import"
    Multi = False
    DataFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=Filt, _
                                           FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
                                           Title:=Title, _
                                           MultiSelect:=Multi)

    If DataFile = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected"
    Else
        'Open the file selected by the user
        Set WBdata = Workbooks.Open(DataFile)
        Set ws = WBdata.Sheets("Sheet2")

        'Get the data
        With ws
            .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit

            'Close and Select Cell (1,1)
            WBdata.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great man! Thank you very much, it works! I need to dig into the `.Cells` syntax to understand it further.