# How do I store a cell range into a variable?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

So, I wanted to make a "nicer" reference to a cell range soas not to have to copy/paste it throughout my method, but the following code does not work:

```
Dim cellRange As Range
' fieldIndex = 1, startRow = 10, lastRow = 20
cellRange = s.Range(Cells(startRow, fieldIndex), Cells(lastRow, fieldIndex))
```

What am I missing?  I can use it in other ways just fine:

```
s.Range(Cells(startRow, fieldIndex), Cells(lastRow, fieldIndex)).Value = "bob"
```

Comment: You have to use the word `Set` to set the range. Also see this link since you are using the `Cells` Object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757265/excel-vba-error-copying-a-range-from-external-workbook/14763491#14763491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Set` for objects like a Range:

```
Dim cellRange As Range
' fieldIndex = 1, startRow = 10, lastRow = 20
Set cellRange = s.Range(Cells(startRow, fieldIndex), Cells(lastRow, fieldIndex))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thank you.  Why do I need the `Set` in this case?

Comment: @Jon, see this SO answer about the `Set` keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10196620/293078

Comment: Hi Doug,  Thank you, that lead me to query what is a default member, which lead me to [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) with an example nr the bottom of the page that nicely illustrates setting both the object and the default member.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Sid you may also need to clarify the Cells part, like this for example.

```
With s
   Dim cellRange As Range
   ' fieldIndex = 1, startRow = 10, lastRow = 20
   Set cellRange = .Range(.Cells(startRow, fieldIndex), .Cells(lastRow, fieldIndex))
End with
```

Comment: Why would that be (needing a '.' before the 'Cells')?

Comment: The `With s` code code above it means that it becomes the equivalent of `s.Cells(...)`. If it works without it it doesn't matter, but you may find that Cells sometimes doesn't have a context depending on what you're doing.